Azure VM availability alert rule
Please let me know how to stop generating / processing VM availability alert if the shutdown is initiated by user or automation account. Ie, I want to get the VM availability alert to be processed (don't send email ) if the VM is shutdown/stopped by user/ automation account. But need to receive alert if the VM is crashed or VM is not available due to any other issues (eg if the VM down due to outage at MS end).Please note that VM insights is not enabled.
I want to get the VM availability alert to be processed (don't send email ) if the VM is shutdown/stopped by user/ automation account. But need to receive alert if the VM is crashed or VM is not available due to any other issues (eg if the VM down due to outage at MS end).


I want to get the VM availability alert to be processed (don't send email) if the VM is shutdown/stopped by user/ automation account.

As you mentioned you did not want to send an email for triggering the alerts, so instead of that use an Azure automation runbook or a logic app or a function to send and trigger alerts for VM shutdown or stopped by a user.
Firstly, run below KQL query of Azure Activity with the relevant operation name and resource provider as shown below.
AzureActivity
| where ResourceProvider == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| where OperationNameValue == "stopped" 
| where Caller == "user"

Once you have executed the query, create an alert rule and add a scheduled query alert under an automation account runbook instead of sending an email as detailed in the below given MS Doc.
Eg: If the VM is deallocated or shut down by a user, you can log this specific event. Follow the same for other events as well.

Reference document to Trigger alert with automation account.
